# Return PartialView in MVC3 Area is not searching in area

Tags: partial-views, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on an ASP.Net MVC 3 RC project.  I have one area named Drivers. I have a LoadPartial() action in a controller in the Drivers area that returns a PartialView(string, object);  When this is returned I get an error on my webpage that says "The partial view 'PublicAttendanceCode' was not found." It searched the following locations:

```
~/Views/AttendanceEvent/PublicAttendanceCode.aspx
~/Views/AttendanceEvent/PublicAttendanceCode.ascx
~/Views/Shared/PublicAttendanceCode.aspx
~/Views/Shared/PublicAttendanceCode.ascx
~/Views/AttendanceEvent/PublicAttendanceCode.cshtml
~/Views/AttendanceEvent/PublicAttendanceCode.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/PublicAttendanceCode.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/PublicAttendanceCode.vbhtml
```

**Why is it not searching in the Drivers Area?**

I have the following pretty basic routes in Global.asax.cs:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home",
              action = "Index",
              id = UrlParameter.Optional  // Parameter defaults
            }
    );
}
```

And in DriversAreaRegistration.cs

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "Drivers_default",
        "Drivers/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { action = "RequestLeave", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

**What am I missing that will make it look in the drivers area for the partial?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you providing area name to PartialView() method? I think you should be passing it in new { area = "Drivers" } as routeValues parameter.

Answer (score 2):

The way that the MVC view engines know the area that they should look in is based on the *route* that was used to process the request.

In the case of the controller action that you have, are you certain that the request was processed by the area's route definition, or is it possible that the request was processed by the more general route that you defined in global.asax?

Comment: Well, I'm guessing that it is using the route in global.asax, but since it hit the DriverArea Controller, shouldn't it be looking there for the route as well? And if not, how would I fix this so that it will look for the partial in the drivers area?

Answer (score 1):

There are only four overloads of the method [`PartialView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.partialview.aspx) and it seems like neither of them accept `routeValues` as a parameter.

I solved this problem like this:

```
return PartialView(
    VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Areas/MyArea/Views/Shared/MyView.cshtml"));
```

It works, but looks ugly.

Answer (score 1):

This works too:

```
return PartialView("~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/MyView.cshtml", model);
```